# Print minimum integer of list's elements based on indices from other list

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, python-3.5

I have two lists a and b(both have same length) where the list b has only 1, 2 and 3 as its elements(random repetition allowed).Now , for all the indices of 1 in list 'b' I want to print a min integer from list a.And same for 2 and 3 in list 'b'. For example:

```
      a = [10,33,42,17,9,32,33,43,12,2,5,22]
      b = [3,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,2]
```

As the indices at which 1 is(in list 'b') are 1,4,7,9 respectively I want to print the minimum integer (answer for example is 2) from list 'a' at such indices. The same should be done for 2 and 3 from list 'b'. Also if it is possible to calculate that for 1, 2 and 3 altogether from list 'b' then please tell.

Expected output(according to the example):

```
The min integer for 1, 2 and 3 are 2, 5 and 10 respectively.
```

**a and b here are just an example. Please answer if a and b are taken as user inputs and b has the same constraints i.e b can contain only 1, 2 and 3(with random repetition).**

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: add some code to your question to help us understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Please check the question now.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output is from this input? I'm afraid I can't follow the description easily.

Comment: okay let me edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
a = [10,33,42,17,9,32,33,43,12,2,5,22]
b = [3,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,2]

low = min(b)
high = max(b)

minimum = [min([a[i] for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]==n]) for n in range(low,high+1)]
output = "".join(["The min integer for ", ", ".join(map(str,range(low,high-1))), " and ", str(high), " are ", ", ".join(map(str,minimum[:-1])), " and ", str(minimum[-1]), " respectively."])
print(output)
```

Output:

```
The min integer for 1 and 3 are 2, 5 and 10 respectively.
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want the user to enter the numbers of `b` and check if they are 1,2 or 3, you can do this:

```
def enterInput(b, length):
    print("List length: ", length)
    for i in range(length):
        while True:
            elem = int(input("Enter element " + str(i) + ": "))
            if not elem in [1,2,3]:
                print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
            else:
                b.append(elem)
                break

a = [10,33,42,17,9,32,33,43,12,2,5,22]
b = []

length = len(a)
enterInput(b, length)
```

and then make calculations as above.

**UPDATE**

For list `a`, you could go as following:

```
def enterInputNumbers(a):
    while True:
        length = int(input("Enter list's length: "))
        if length > 0:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid list length. Please try again.")

    for i in range(length):
        elem = int(input("Enter element " + str(i) + ": "))
        a.append(elem)
```

So, the whole code will be:

```
def enterInputNumbers(a):
    while True:
        length = int(input("Enter list's length: "))
        if length > 0:
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid list length. Please try again.")

    for i in range(length):
        elem = int(input("Enter element " + str(i) + ": "))
        a.append(elem)

def enterInput(b, length):
    print("List length: ", length)
    for i in range(length):
        while True:
            elem = int(input("Enter element " + str(i) + ": "))
            if not elem in [1,2,3]:
                print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
            else:
                b.append(elem)
                break

#a = [10,33,42,17,9,32,33,43,12,2,5,22]
#b = [3,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,2]
a = []
b = []

enterInputNumbers(a)
length = len(a)
enterInput(b, length)

low = min(b)
high = max(b)

minimum = [min([a[i] for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]==n]) for n in range(low,high+1)]
output = "".join(["The min integer for ", ", ".join(map(str,range(low,high-1))), " and ", str(high), " are ", ", ".join(map(str,minimum[:-1])), " and ", str(minimum[-1]), " respectively."])
print(output)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you please generalise it?  like if 'a' and 'b' are user input and 'b' has the same constraints (i.e  it only has 1,2,3 as its elements).Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify it please? Do you mean like checking if all elements of `b` are only 1 or 2 or 3?

Comment: No, the input for 'b' should be only from 1,2 and 3. Also can you suggest me a better title for the question? Thank you!

Comment: The title could be "Print minimum integer of list's elements based on indices from other list" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to understand if you group the elements according to the corresponding item in `b`. The following is a generalized algorithm that doesn't hardcode. You can pass in any values for `b` and it will return the minimum corresponding in `a`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def min_el(a, b):
  groups = defaultdict(list)
  for el_a, el_b in zip(a, b):
    groups[el_b].append(el_a)
  return groups.keys(), [min(groups[key]) for key in groups.keys()]

a = [10,33,42,17,9,32,33,43,12,2,5,22]
b = [3,1,3,2,1,3,2,1,3,1,2,2]
print(min_el(a, b)) # ([1, 2, 3], [2, 5, 10])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach :

```
a = [10, 33, 42, 17, 9, 32, 33, 43, 12, 2, 5, 22]
b = [3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2]

min_value={}
for j,i in enumerate(b):
    if i not in min_value:
        min_value[i]=[a[j]]
    else:
        min_value[i].append(a[j])

print({i:min(j) for i,j in min_value.items()})
```

output:

```
{1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 10}
```